# How To Calculate Process Size from TLB size and mean memory access time

Tags: memory, tlb, page-tables

In a paged memory system where the entire process is loaded in memory(not demand paging), you have a 35-entry TLB. Assume that the probability of a memory access being in any one page is the same (unlike normal). If the TLB search time is 5nsec and memory access time is 50nsec, how large is the process in the pages if the effective access time is 70nsec?

How do I calculate the size of the process??

Comment: How the "effective access time" is defined? What is [TLB](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/vm-tlbs.pdf) (http://ostep.org book is used here) and why is it needed? What kind of MMU and page walk is used (is it one level, two level or more level [page table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_table))?

Comment: @osgx one level I'm assuming. This is a homework problem and this is all I was provided.

Comment: no, you don't. There was also half-semester CS course before this homework. How did you define "effective access time" and did you learn what is the TLB?

Comment: @osgx I do not know what is meant by "effective" access time as opposed the aforementioned access time. And I am aware what the TLB is, and what it does(virtually maps pages to addresses and reduces time to access information from said addressed location)

Comment: Some ideas added as answer; no full solution here. Also check http://stackoverflow.com/a/14193216 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18550370/calculate-the-effective-access-time for possible definitions of effective access time.

Answer (score 0):

This system uses virtual memory in process, and to make access to memory, virtual address should be translated into physical. This translation is stored in the same physical memory using some variant of "page table" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_table).

In variant without TLB (TLB of size zero entry), every program access will need to read translation entry from page table before real access can be made. So, effective (average) memory access time will be equal to 2 * main memory access time.

```
eff_time(TLB_size_0) = 2 * main_memory_access_time
```

TLB is optimization (check http://ostep.org book for more [details of real world TLB](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/vm-tlbs.pdf)), which caches several recently used translations (and every translation entry describes 1 page). In ideal case all virtual addresses used by program will hit TLB, and there will be only latency of TLB added to memory access time. With 35-entry TLB this will be true for programs (or periods of time) when no more than 35 pages are accessed.

But when program does uniform memory accesses and uses more pages (has bigger size in page count) than can be stored in TLB, some accesses will need to do "page table walk" (in case of 1 level page table - 1 additional memory access) to refill some TLB entry. If 1/5 of program memory accesses miss TLB (and 4/5 don't), mean effective access time will be like

```
eff_time (TLB_miss_rate_of_1_over_5) = (1-1/5) * full_access_time_with_TLB_hit + 1/5 * full_access_time_with_TLB_miss
```

where full_access_time_with_TLB_hit is time to do successful search in TLB and do 1 main memory access, and full_access_time_with_TLB_miss is time to do unsucessful TLB search, access page table (by reading main memory), (possibly refill TLB, and redo search if you MMU is not optimized) and then doing access of memory which was required by application.